# wf-loading class not appearing on website

Tags: fonts

We are currently using Google's WebFont Loader to load our custom @font-face fonts.  The tool is supposed to eliminate fout by allowing us to use css classes to hide the text while the fonts are loading.  Unfortunately, it seems like the class on the html tag is always wf-active so the fout still shows.  Does anyone have an idea of why the wf-loading class is not being shown?

In case you want to take a look our website is http://wiredimpact.com and the documentation for Google WebFont Loader is at https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader.

Thank you.

Comment: I am having the same issue: the .wf-loading class is not being appended to the html class, so I cannot target this in CSS. It's a bummer.

Answer (score 3):

I created a hack to work around this issue. Firstly, I hard coded the `wf-loading` class to the `html` element.

```
<html class="wf-loading">
```

The WebFont loader removes this class and replaces it with the relevant font classes once loaded, so everything works as expected. However, I don't want to be in a situation where the WebFont loader doesn't load and the `wf-loading` class in not removed, so as a fallback, I added a script to remove the class after 3 seconds:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('html').removeClass('wf-loading');
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

@Astrotim, your answer would work except in the cases where

1) The user doesn't have javascript. Then wf-loading class never leaves.

2) You end up removing wf-loading with your 3 second timeout before webfont loader is done.

I used modernizr to approach the same problem (*). Just hard code no-js and wf-loading into the html element. Then you can use .no-js.wf-loading as a no javascript fallback, and .js.wf-loading while webfont loader is getting the fonts and  .js.wf-active,.js.wf-inactive for when it's done.

(*) Modernizr will look for no-js in the html element and change it to js if javascript is enabled.